# Unstable connection to localhost from nginx to second container in the same ECS task

Tags: nginx, amazon-ecs

I am using `awsvpc` network mode in ECS task definition.
In the task I describe two containers that serve different ports - container with nginx serve 80 and second serve 8042.

In nginx I request second container, using `127.0.0.1` as address in `proxy_pass`. Also I tried `localhost` with the same results.

It do successfully get responses.. in most of the times.
But in something like 20% request fail with error `connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream`.

I fixed that not using `127.0.0.1` but the ECS service IP that I register in AWS Cloup map and can resolve using DNS.
That worked already for a number of days without a single error.

But now I have two concerns:

1. It's kind of stupid and ineffective to go to the same host using Cloud map.
2. I do not understand what was wrong and means it could bite me again at any moment.

nginx config

```
location /healthcheck {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;

        proxy_set_header Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header accept "multipart/related";
        expires      0;
        add_header   Cache-Control private;

        proxy_buffering off;

        proxy_pass http://$pacs_server:8042/dicom-web/studies/0/;
}
```

It's 100% reproducible - change to DNS name and it's ok, change to localhost and immediately you see this errors.

I connected to the ECS container with `ecs exec` and run `curl` manually - no errors with `localhost`.

So this is something specific to nginx.

Comment: I have plenty of ECS Fargate tasks running, with Nginx proxying requests to another container in the same task over `localhost`, and I have never encountered a situation where that caused a "connection refused" error. When those errors are occurring, are you sure the other container hasn't crashed or something? You really shouldn't need to use CloudMap for this, but you will need to do some debugging and log searching on your end to try to identify the problem, as this is something related to your specific system. It is not something common to ECS Fargate.

Comment: I totally agree with you. I found nothing about such issues with FARGATE so that should be something wrong in my tasks. But nonetheless I just change only single things - Cloud Map name replace with localhost. And just immediately I see again this error. It work but sometimes cannot connect. Changed back to DNS name - like a charm, no single error. Crazy.

Comment: And when it can't connect, do you use something like `ecs exec` to debug the issue? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-exec.html

Comment: Thank you, you made my day! I did not know I can connect to ECS container.
Running curl on it I do not see this errors like I see in nginx log when using localhost. So from container it work, why it fail from nginx/lua? Placed the lua code in the question